# one command line grep and word count recursively

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, wc

I can do the following using a for loop

```
    for f in *.txt; do grep 'RINEX' $f |wc -l; done
```

Is there any possibility to get an individual file report by running one liner?

Meaning that I want to grep & wc one file at the time in a similar fashion like

```
    grep 'RINEX' *.txt
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    grep -c 'RINEX' *.txt
```

returns the name of each file and its corresponding number of occurrences. Thx @Evert

Comment: How does `grep 'RINEX' *.txt` operate one file at a time. It's actually your for-loop that works on one file at a time.  (Btw: `$f.txt` or just `$f`?)

Comment: Or are you looking for the count option to grep? "-c, --count: Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output."

Comment: Thx. I corrected the first one. The 2nd answer was the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

grep is not the right tool for this task.

grep does line based match, e.g. line `grep 'o' <<< "fooo"` will return `1` line. however we have `3` `o`s.

This one-liner should do what you want:

```
awk -F'RINEX' 'FILENAME!=f{if(f)print f,s;f=FILENAME;s=0}
               {s+=(NF-1)}
               END{print f,s}' /path/*.txt
```